# adapting an action to a div class

Tags: java, html, jsp

I used the code below as my log-in form which calls the action 'loginRequestHandler.jsp'.

```
   <form action="loginRequestHandler.jsp">
                <table cellpadding="5">
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>UserID</b></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="email" required/></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><b>Passwort</b></td>
                        <td><input type="password" name="password" required/></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Login"/></td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
            </form>
```

How can I adapt my needs to the following snippet? I recently downloaded a responsive template but this login form is killing me...

```
<div class="login-form">
     <h1>SmartHome</h1>
     <div class="form-group ">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
       <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group log-status">
       <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
       <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
     </div>
      <span class="alert">Invalid Credentials</span>
      <a class="link" href="#">Lost your password?</a>
     <button type="button" class="log-btn" >Log in</button>    
   </div>
```

Comment: You need to add a `<form></form>` tag to cover your input and button

Comment: thanks @TuyenNguyen =) works!